# Почему метод receive не блокирует поток?

Tags: c#, .net, сокет

Чего хочу: получить данные с удалённого модуля по сокету.
Как реализую: пока в одном потоке, чтобы проще было делать отладку. Конечно, мой подход не супер гибкий, но цель - реализовать некую финкциональность, а не написать супер крутое ПО по паттернам и принципам SOLID. Так что архитектура такая:

Класс DataGenerator. У него есть публичные поля IsDataGenerated и Data. Алгоритм, по которому он "создаёт" данные:
1. Создаётся TCP-соединение с удалённым модулем.
2. Отправляет ему запрос.
3. Принимает данные.
4. Записывает в Data полученное значение.
5. Устанавли вает IsDataGenerated в true.

```
static class DataGenerator
{
    public static bool IsDataGenerated { get; private set; }

    public static string Data { get; private set; }

    static Socket _remoteDataGeneratorConnection = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    static IdsGenerator()
    {
        IsDataGenerated = false;

        ConnectSockets();
    }

    private static void ConnectSockets()
    {
        ConnectToDataGenerator();
    }

    private static void ConnectToDataGenerator()
    {
        IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(Settings.GetLocalIPAddress());

        IPEndPoint remoteDataGeneratorEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, /* port */ 48209);

        _remoteDataGeneratorConnection.Connect(remoteDataGeneratorEndPoint);
    }

    public static void GenerateData()
    {
        IsDataGenerated = false;

        SendRequestToGenerator(_remoteDataGeneratorConnection);
        Data = GetStringResponseFromSocket(_remoteDataGeneratorConnection);

        IsDataGenerated = true;
    }

    private static void SendRequestToGenerator(Socket socket)
    {
        byte[] msg = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
        int bytesSent = socket.Send(msg);
    }

    private static string GetStringResponseFromSocket(Socket socket)
    {
        string receivedData = null;

        byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[sizeof(Int32)]; // 4 bytes - size of (received) Int32
        _remoteDataGeneratorConnection.Receive(rcvLenBytes);

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(rcvLenBytes);

        int receivingDataLength = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvLenBytes, 0);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[receivingDataLength];

        int bytesReceived = _remoteDataGeneratorConnection.Receive(bytes); // returns count of received bytes

        if (bytesReceived != 0) // data received
            receivedData = Settings.SocketsDataEncoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesReceived); // converting byte array to string

        return receivedData;
    }
}
```

Как использую этот класс (да, способ костыльный; думала о событийной моделе, но сейчас не об этом):

```
private string GetData()
    {
        DataGenerator.GenerateData();

        while (!DataGenerator.IsDataGenerated)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

       return DataGenerator.Data;
    }
```

В чём проблема: хотя в коде нету явного создания потоков, вызовов асинхронных методов, но метод GetData() постоянно возвращает **предыдущее** значение. То есть сначала пустую строку, потом строку, которая была сгенерирована при первом запросе, хотя уже был отправлен второй, и т.д. Получается, где-то создаётся второй поток, а основной просто не ждёт его завершения, устанавливает IsDataGenerated в true и сразу же забирает старое значение. В отладке всё отлично работает. То есть второй поток успевает записать данные до получения их значения. Как заставить основной поток дождаться получения данных с сокета?

Comment: Что это за метод `static IdsGenerator()` и что из себя представляет класс `settings`

Comment: @Digital Core это конструктор. То же, что и DataGenerator. Просто упростила код, как могла, чтобы проще было разобраться. Забыла переименовать конструктор.

Comment: @DigitalCore settings по сути выполняет задачу app.config. Класс, состоящий с публичных констант (литералы для приложения). Просто мне проще так получать нужные приложения литералы, чем с app.config. Да, для изменения значений литералов нужно будет каждый раз перекомпилировать приложение, но я не хочу заморачиваться по поводу этого.

Comment: уж как то не похоже на литералы `Settings.SocketsDataEncoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesReceived);`

Comment: @Digital это чтобы не менять во всём проекте Encoding.UTF8 на новую кодировку, если захочу её изменить. Всё же значение генерируется на этапе компиляции и не меняется в ходе выполнения программы.